# how to add shortcode into div on storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hello can you help me,

i want to add shortcode after this `<div class="customads1"` and `<div class="customads2"`

this is the complete code i added in the function.php

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'fuyn_footer_widgets', 11 );
function fuyn_footer_widgets(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
 global $woocommerce ; 

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}
echo '<div class="customads" style="width: 100%;display: flex;">
    <div class="customads1" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">Shortcode.</div>
    <div class="customads2" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">Shortcode.</div>
</div>';
}
}
```

how to do it,

this is my short code

```
[sc name="ads"][/sc]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a shortcode inside a PHP code on WordPress. You need to use [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) like this:

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'fuyn_footer_widgets', 11 );
function fuyn_footer_widgets(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
 global $woocommerce ; 

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}
echo '<div class="customads" style="width: 100%;display: flex;">
    <div class="customads1" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">'.do_shortcode('[sc name="ads"]').'</div>
    <div class="customads2" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">'.do_shortcode('[sc name="ads"]').'</div>
</div>';
    }
}
```

**You can also structure it better like this:**

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'fuyn_footer_widgets', 11 );
function fuyn_footer_widgets(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
 global $woocommerce ; 

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}
$shortcodeValue = do_shortcode('[sc name="ads"]');
?>
<div class="customads" style="width: 100%;display: flex;">
    <div class="customads1" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">
   <?php echo $shortcodeValue; ?>
   </div>
    <div class="customads2" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;"> 
       <?php echo $shortcodeValue;?> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

**OR**

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'fuyn_footer_widgets', 11 );
function fuyn_footer_widgets(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
 global $woocommerce ; 

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}
$shortcodeValue = do_shortcode('[sc name="ads"]');
?>
echo '<div class="customads" style="width: 100%;display: flex;">
    <div class="customads1" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">'.$shortcodeValue.'</div>
    <div class="customads2" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">'.$shortcodeValue.'</div>
</div>';
}
}
```

**Note: `do_shortcode()` always requires an `echo`.**

Comment: Hello @HowardE i believe you're new to the Wordpress ecosystem. Please check the usage of do_shortcode() here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/   it must always be echoed. I've been using it for years now. Also, just to reply to your "Shortcodes must not produce output" statement. Please look at how visual composer works. And also look at how Woocommerce shortcodes works to show product loops.

Comment: I'm not insulting anyone here. By your statement i though you're new. Because there is nothing above which is a shortcode function and doing echo. Everyone's opinions/experiences are respected. Instead of a statement if you could point out a line that's incorrect that must be helpful. –

Comment: Hi @vinay, I tried the first way and it works fine, Thank you very much

Comment: See my code above, I use 2 conditions `if` first if in checkout page second if total price 0, I tried so far its fine, is there a better way to create those 2 conditions, thanks

Comment: Yes, you can combine those 2 conditions.               if(!is_checkout() && $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) { return; }           but make sure you use global $woocommerce; before that if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'fuyn_footer_widgets', 11 );
function fuyn_footer_widgets(){
    if( is_checkout() ){
 global $woocommerce ; 

if ( $woocommerce->cart->total != 0 ) {
    return;
}
echo '<div class="customads" style="width: 100%;display: flex;">
    <div class="customads1" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">Shortcode.</div> ' . do_shortcode( '[sc name="ads"]' ) . '
    <div class="customads2" style="width: 50%;background: bisque;margin: 5px;">Shortcode.</div>
</div>';
}
}
```